# create floating labels in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

Can someone help me to create html for below?
I am creating a simple html progress tracker, which looks similar to stacked bar chart. I would like to display title labels pointing to each stack in the graph. How can I do that? It should work on IE8.

Here's a fiddle I have created so far
[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/skyz37f9/) ,
but unable to create title labels which you see around the graph

```
<div class="colWrapper">
        <div class="bar" style="background-color:#4cff00;width:40%">
            <div align="center" class="barLabel"><span>Done</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar" style="background-color:#ff0000;width:5%">
            <div align="center" class="barLabel"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar" style="background-color:#00ffff;width:50%">
            <div align="center" class="barLabel"><span>Pending</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar" style="background-color:#0094ff;width:5%">
            <div align="center" class="barLabel"><span></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Below is the prototype I am trying to create,

[image]

Comment: How do you expect to handle overlaping if like done is too thin and collide with the neighbor label? Maybe on hover labels would be simpler to implement.

Comment: if the stack layer is too thin then we will not show them. We can either mouse hover to see the label. But the one you see on the side, for example start date,today, end date, impeded, future enhancement need to be floating around the bar pointing the stack region.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about this?
Try using pseudo elements,  (:before/:after),

and absolutely position them above the bars, and below.

i made a quick fiddle showing one of the : its supported by ie8

```
https://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/

https://jsfiddle.net/skyz37f9/5/

<-- i did a quick test on browserstack to confirm ie8
```

Hope this helps

Ps u can also combine hover:after (if u only wish to show on hover)

```css
.colWrapper{
    margin-top:50px;
    height:60px;
    width:500px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}

.barContainer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:100%;
}

.bar{
    height:100%;
    float:left; 
    font-size:12px;
    position: relative;
}

.bar1:after {
  content: 'Start Date: \A Jan 1st, 2014';
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: pre;
}

.bar1:before {
  content: '';
    border-left: 3px solid black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top: -20px;
}

.bar2:hover:after {
 content: 'Impeded';
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -35px;
 width: auto;
 white-space: pre;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: -35%;
}
.bar2:hover:before {
 content: '';
 border-left: 3px solid black;
 height: 20px;
 width: 100%;
 position:absolute;
 bottom: -20px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -3px;
}

.barLabel{
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="colWrapper">
    <div class="bar bar1" style="background-color:#4cff00;width:40%">
        <div align="center" class="barLabel"><span>Done</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar bar2" style="background-color:#ff0000;width:5%">
        <div align="center" class="barLabel"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar" style="background-color:#00ffff;width:50%">
        <div align="center" class="barLabel"><span>Pending</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar" style="background-color:#0094ff;width:5%">
        <div align="center" class="barLabel"><span></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I am looking for. Thanks! Can you also show, how can I do it for the labels below the bar? For labels like Impeded, Future Enhancements?

Comment: updated the answer with labels below (just use same value's but bottom: -?px instead of top :)

Answer (score 3):

```css
.colWrapper {
  height: 60px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 2em;
}
.barContainer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.bar {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.barLabel {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.bar {
  position: relative;
}
.label-below {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
.label-above {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="colWrapper">
  <div class="bar" style="background-color:#4cff00;width:40%">
    <div align="center" class="barLabel"><span>Done</span>
    </div>
    <div class="label-above">Start Date:
      <br>1 Jun 2000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar" style="background-color:#ff0000;width:5%">
    <div align="center" class="barLabel"></div>
    <div class="label-above">Today: Mar 2 2014</div>
    <div class="label-below">Impeeded</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar" style="background-color:#00ffff;width:50%">
    <div align="center" class="barLabel"><span>Pending</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar" style="background-color:#0094ff;width:5%">
    <div align="center" class="barLabel"><span></span>
      <div class="label-above">End Date: Dec 31 2014</div>
      <div class="label-below">Future Enhancement</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it in a cleaner flexible way is like this

That way you avoid absolute positioning problems. And I like how the HTML structure looks like.

```css
/*the entire bar */
.bar {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
/*each bar segment */
.bar li {
  display: inline-block;
  -border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}

/*each bar segment fill thing*/
.bar li div {
  background: gray;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

/*segments labels*/
.bar li label {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.bar li:first-child label {
  text-align: left;
}
.bar li:last-child label {
  text-align: right;
}

/* arrow */
.bar label:last-child:before{
  display: block;
  content: "|";
}
.bar label:first-child:after{
  display: block;
  content: "|";
}
```

```html
<ul class="bar">
  
  <li style="width: 20%">
    <label>above</label>
    <div style="background-color: red">inside</div>
    <label>below</label>
  </li>
  
  <li style="width: 30%">
    <label>above</label>
    <div style="background-color: yellow">inside</div>
    <label>below</label>
  </li>
  
  <li style="width: 20%">
    <label>above</label>
    <div style="background-color: blue">inside</div>
    <label>below</label>
  </li>

  <li style="width: 30%">
    <label>above</label>
    <div style="background-color: magenta">inside</div>
    <label>below</label>
  </li>
  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt using divs with borders before and after

https://jsfiddle.net/skyz37f9/3/

```css
.colWrapper {
    height:60px;
    width:500px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.barContainer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:100%;
}
.bar {
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    font-size:12px;
}
.barLabel {
    margin-top:10px;
}
.label1 {
    width:200px!important;
    background-color:#fff;
    display:table-cell;
    font-size:small;
}
#labelWrapper {
    height:50px;
    width:500px;
    position:relative;
    border-right:1px solid;
    border-left:1px solid;
}
.label2 {
    width:50px;
    background-color:#fff;
    display:table-cell;
    border-left:1px solid;
    font-size:small;
}
.label3 {
    width:250px;
    background-color:#fff;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:right;
    font-size:small;
}
#status {
    height:50px;
    width:500px;
    position:relative;
}
.stat1 {
    width:210px!important;
    background-color:#fff;
    display:table-cell;
    border-right:1px solid;
    font-size:small;
    text-align:right;
}
.stat2 {
    width:280px!important;
    background-color:#fff;
    display:table-cell;
    border-right:1px solid;
    font-size:small;
    text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="labelWrapper">
    <div class="label1">Start:
        <br>Jan 1 2014</div>
    <div class="label2">Today:
        <br>Mar 2 2014</div>
    <div class="label3">End Date:
        <br>Dec 31 2014</div>
</div>
<div class="colWrapper">
    <div class="bar" style="background-color:#4cff00;width:40%">
        <div align="center" class="barLabel"><span>Done</span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar" style="background-color:#ff0000;width:5%">
        <div align="center" class="barLabel"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar" style="background-color:#00ffff;width:50%">
        <div align="center" class="barLabel"><span>Pending</span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar" style="background-color:#0094ff;width:5%">
        <div align="center" class="barLabel"><span></span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="status">
    <div class="stat1">Impeded</div>
    <div class="stat2">Future Enhancement</div>
</div>
```